# Spring Integration: gateway bean not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I try to using spring integration in different jars.
In the A.jar si-context.xml:

```
    <context:annotation-config />
    <int:annotation-config />

    <int:channel id="upperServiceChannel">
        <int:priority-queue />
    </int:channel>

    <int:gateway id="upperGateway" default-request-timeout="5000"
        default-reply-timeout="5000" default-request-channel="upperServiceChannel"
        service-interface="com.company.proj.gw.IUpperStringConversation">
        <int:method name="toUpperCase" />
    </int:gateway>


    <bean id="toUpperCaseService" class="com.company.proj.service.ToUpperCaseService" />
    <int:service-activator id="serviceActivatorToUpperCase"
        input-channel="upperServiceChannel" method="toUpperCase" ref="toUpperCaseService" />

    <int:poller id="poller" default="true" fixed-delay="1000" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company"/>
```

In a bean I'm using this gateway:

```
 @Component(value = "upper")
    public class UpperAdapter extends AAdapter<Message<String>> {

    @Autowired
    IUpperStringConversation gw;
```

It's working. The problem is, if I try to using my UpperAdapter from an other project (B.jar).
b-context.xml:

```
<import resource="classpath*:/*si-context.xml" />
<context:annotation-config />
<int:annotation-config />


    @Component(value="router")
public class Router {

    @Autowired
    private Map<String, AAdapter<?>> adapters;
```

And here I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'upper': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.company.proj.gw.IUpperStringConversation com.company.proj.adapter.UpperAdapter.gw; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.company.proj.gw.IUpperStringConversation] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

After I set the spring log level to debug, get this information:

```
DEBUG o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Ignored because not a concrete top-level class: URL [jar:file:/home/tomto/Documents/workspace-sts/integration-fw/src/main/resources/META-INF/lib/integration-fw-module-string-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/company/proj/gw/IUpperStringConversation.class]
```

Of course, it's true, becouse (maybe I'm wrong ;)) it would be at runtime generated gateway by spring.

The IUpperStringConversation:

```
public interface IUpperStringConversation {
    public String toUpperCase(String text);
}
```

What I missed?

Thx!

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework`; you'll get copious debug logs for xml parsing, bean discovery/creation etc.

Comment: Have you ever solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue, our gateways were not getting injected into our service object:

```
Project structure:
----------------
-parent/
-common/
   --gateways defined here
-module-a/
-module-b/
```

The exception message received in module-b was:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ... Injection of autowired dependencies failed
...
IllegalArgumentException: Class must not be null
```

Apparently the issue was being caused by conflicting dependencies we had on the module-b classpath. After we cleaned up the Spring dependencies in pom.xml it worked!